# set expire headers through PHP

Tags: php, apache

We are rendering minified css / js through php with following expire headers

```
header('Expires:'.gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s', 1407595380 + 3600 * 24 * 90).' GMT');
header('Cache-Control: public');
header('Last-Modified: 1407595380');
header('Content-type: text/css');
```

Response headers we are getting mentioned in-line

```
Cache-Control   public
Connection  Keep-Alive
Content-Encoding    gzip
Content-Length  3224
Content-Type    text/css
Date    Mon, 11 Aug 2014 14:54:55 GMT
Expires Fri, 07 Nov 2014 14:43:00 GMT
Keep-Alive  timeout=5, max=100
Last-Modified   1407595380
Pragma  no-cache
Server  Apache/2.2.22 (Ubuntu)
```

But every time i refresh my page , browser gives me 200 response code instead of 304. Browser is not using own cache for php generated minified files and rest css js having 304 code on subsequent requests.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
$timeToCache = 3600 * 24 * 90;
header('Expires:'.gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s', 1407595380 + $timeToCache).' GMT');
header('Cache-Control: public');
header('Cache-Control: max-age='.$timeToCache);
header('Last-Modified: 1407595380');
header('Content-type: text/css');
header('Pragma: cache');
```

Comment: If you are using Apache, you can create an .htaccess file with the content:
`<Files "minified.php">  
Header unset Pragma  
Header set Pragma "cache"  
</Files>`

Comment: Please explain your answer some. SO is not just about answering questions, but learning how and why things work.

Answer (score 0):

`Pragma: no-cache` might give you clue.

Although it is for legacy HTTP/1.0, Try setting `Pragma: cache` .